# c: Access violation writing location using dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, access-violation

I am currently working on a project which uses 2D arrays.
I have a function which makes a 2D array of integers, and others that find the shortest path etc, and they all work perfectly.

However, I'm running into issues with another part, where I am getting 'Access Violation errors' when attempting to initialise these arrays:

```
    // |V|x|V| arrays
int** fwdistance = malloc(vertexCount*vertexCount*(sizeof(int)));
int** fwnext = malloc(vertexCount*vertexCount*(sizeof(int)));

for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++) {
        fwdistance[i][j] = INT_MAX; // Distances = infinity
        fwnext[i][j] = -1;          // Next nodes are unknown
    }
}
```

Error occurs when attempting to initialise fwdistance[0][0].
As I mentioned, I have other arrays initialised the same way, and they work perfectly:

```
// Initialises arrays for Dijkstra's Shortest Path algorithm
int *distance = malloc(vertexCount*(sizeof(int)));
int *previous = malloc(vertexCount*(sizeof(int)));
```

I honestly have no idea!

Comment: shouldn't you use `fwdistance[i*vertexCount+j]` your allocated array is still 1d

Comment: You can't allocate a 2D array with a single malloc call. And the types in your allocation are wrong for a 1D allocation too.

Answer (score 3):

You allocate a plain array of `int`s, but you access it as if it were a jagged array of `int` pointers. This causes undefined behavior, which ultimately leads to segmentation fault.

There are two solutions to this problem:

- Make `fwdistance` an `int*` instead of `int**`, and access its elements either with `fwdistance[i*vertexCount+j]` or `fwdistance[j*vertexCount+i]`, depending on the order you choose, or
- Make `fwdistance` a pointer to array, i.e. `int (*fwdistance)[vertexCount] = malloc ...`. This approach would let you keep matrix indexing, i.e. `fwdistance[i][j]`.

Answer (score 2):

if you wanted to create a 2D array you would have to allocate each row (or column ) separately.

```
 int fwdistance[][] = malloc(vertexCount*sizeof(int*));
 for(i=0;i<vertexCount;++i) {
     fwdistance[i] = malloc(vertexCount*sizeof(int));
 }
 ...
 fwdistance[i][j] = -1;
```

Alternatively you could emulate a 2d rectangular array by calculating the offset.

```
 int fwdistance[] = alloc(vertexCount*vertexCount*sizeof(int));
 ...
 fwdistance[i*vertexCount+j] = -1;
```